# PySpark structured streaming and filtered processing for parts

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I want to evaluate a streamed (unbound) data frame within Spark 2.4:

```
time          id   value
6:00:01.000   1     333
6:00:01.005   1     123
6:00:01.050   2     544
6:00:01.060   2     544
```

When all the data of id 1 got into the dataframe and the data of the next id 2 comes I want to do calculations for the complete data of id 1. But how do I do that? I think I cannot use the window functions since I do not know the time in advance that also varies for each id. And I also do not know the id from other sources besides the streamed data frame.

The only solution that come to my mind contains variable comparison (a memory) and a while loop:

```
id_old = 0 # start value
while true:
  id_cur = id_from_dataframe
  if id_cur != id_old: # id has changed
      do calulation for id_cur
      id_old = id_cur
```

But I do not think that this is the right solution. Can you give me a hint or documentation that helps me since I cannot find examples or documentation.

Comment: how do you know that all of the data for id has reached your dataframe since it's a unbounded stream, is it something sequential , i mean id=2 will only come once id=1 has completed arrived in dataframe?

Comment: Yes, the data is sequential. So there should be no new data for id=1 if there is data for id=2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it running with a combination of watermarking and grouping:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

d2 = d1.withWatermark("time", "60 second") \
    .groupby('id', \
             F.window('time', "40 second")) \
    .agg(
         F.count("*").alias("count"), \
         F.min("time").alias("time_start"), \
         F.max("time").alias("time_stop"), \
         F.round(F.avg("value"),1).alias('value_avg'))
```

Most of the documentation only shows the basic stuff with grouping only by time and I saw just one example with another parameter for grouping, so I put my **'id'** there.